# How to rotate polygon to find best fit in Mapnik?

Tags: python, polygon, mapnik

I have a quite simple problem but somehow I just fail to solve it.

There is a polygon and a range xsize and ysize. The x and y size determines the mapnik generated image.

The polygon should now be made to fit best, by deciding if:

- it is good already or
- a x and y swap and later rotation by 90 degress would make it fit best.

Boundary box and Envelope is given, so no problems there.

The problem is realy just the **rotation criterion** which I'm lost in.

I hope you understand the simple problem and can show me an idea how to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: just so I understand are you looking for some code that lets you rotate polygons?